# Power View Add in

Tags: excel-2013, powerview

I'm trying to use Power View from Excel 2013 so I tried to enable the Power View Add in.

I followed steps to enable Power View add-in in excel 2013 , but after opening COM Add-ins option in Excel , i couldn't find "Power View " option.

So the question my question:

Is there anything that is missing during the installation of Excel 2013 ?

Answer (score 0):

Power View is only available in the Professional Plus & Standalone Office SKUs. You check check what SKU of Excel you are using under File > Account under the "Product Information" heading!